# AJAX form not displaying succes or error message

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I've asked this question before, but I still didn't figure it out. I've made some changes, but I unfortunately still didn't get any luck. The form itself works, but it should also display an error or succes message when the user tries to send the form. But instead of showing the message, it sends the form without showing it. have a look at my code:

**HTML**

```
 <form action="" method="POST">
    <ul class="form-style-1">
        <li>
            <input type="text" id="mail-name" name="name" class="field-divided" maxlength="15"  placeholder="Voornaam *" />&nbsp;<input type="text" id="mail-lastname" name="lastname" class="field-divided" maxlength="15" placeholder="Achternaam" >
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="email" id="mail-email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail *" class="field-long" maxlength="40" >
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type ="text" id="mail-phone" name="phone" placeholder="Telefoonnummer" class="field-long" maxlength = "15">
        </li>
        <li>
            <select name="subject" id="mail-subject" class="field-select" >
            <option disabled value="" selected hidden >--Onderwerp-- *</option>
            <option value="Kennismakingsgesprek">Kennismakingsgesprek</option>
            <option value="Meer informatie">Meer informatie</option>
            <option value="activiteit">Aanmelding activiteit</option>
            <option value="Vraag/klacht">Vraag/klacht</option>
            <option value="Contact">Overig</option>
            </select>
        </li>
        <li>
            <textarea name="information" id="mail-information"  placeholder =" Je bericht *"class="field-long field-textarea" maxlength="2000"></textarea>
        </li>
        <button class="mail-submit" id="mail-submit" type="submit" name="submit">Send e-mail</button>
        <span class="form-message"></span>
    </ul>
</form>
```

**JS** (this script is located in the header)

```
$("#mail-submit").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var name = $("#mail-name").val();
  var lastname = $("#mail-lastname").val();
  var email = $("#mail-email").val();
  var phone = $("#mail-phone").val();
  var subject = $("#mail-subject").val();
  var information = $("#mail-information").val();
  $.post("contact.php",
    {
      name: name,
      lastname: lastname,
      email: email,
      phone: phone,
      subject: subject,
      information: information,
      submit: "yes"
    },
    function(data){
        $(".form-message").html( data );
    }
  );
});
```

**PHP** (Located in a PHP file)

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  $email_to = "#";

  $email_subject = "#";

  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $phone = $_POST['phone'];
  $subject = $_POST['subject'];
  $information = $_POST['information'];

  $errorEmpty = false;
  $errorEmail = false;

  if (empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($subject) || empty($information)) {
    echo "<span class='form-error'>Voer alle velden in!</span>";
    $errorEmpty = true;
  }
  elseif (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "<span class='form-error'>Geef een geldig E-mail!</span>";
    $errorEmail = true;
  }
  else {
    $formcontent=" Naam: $name \n\n Achternaam: $lastname \n\n Email: $email \n\n Telefoon: $phone \n\n Onderwerp: $subject \n\n Informatie: $information";
    $mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
    $headers = "From: ". htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']) ." <" . $_POST['email'] . ">\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    mail($email_to, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader);
    echo "<span class='form-success'>E-mail has been sent!</span>";
  }
}
```

This is the AJAX script that I use:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: _"The PHP code is located under the HTML end tag"_ means what? that after all the html (the form) you have the php in the same file? If yes: it should be another file, because now you send back _all_ the html.

Comment: I suppose you'll also have to event.preventDefault() on the form.onSubmit

Comment: Ho boy... @Jeff saw the bug. The form submits by itself..To self.. Ajax does not execute at all... Or the result is lost in the nothingness because the page reloads. And the "result" is outputted below the `</html>`... lolll That is the worst I've seen so far.

Comment: If all code lies in a file, then give us the file content as it is in original, not in pieces.

Comment: I've looked at the response, nothing strange nor were there any errors. I've also included the jQuery library in my project. And yes, I am running on a web server.

I've tried putting the PHP code in a different file and linked it with the form action. When doing so, I get an echo message saying that the form has been sent, unfortunetely not a message on the page itself.

Comment: You have to decide: do you want to use the html form submission (which would refresh the whole page), OR a click event on a button, for the ajax (which will not refresh the whole page)? For the second option you will need no form, but two files. Fore the 1st option you will need only one file and the form, without any ajax.

Comment: @aendeerei Then the second option would be my best bet. I've changed it so that the PHP is not in the same file anymore. But when submitting the form, it redirects me to the PHP file with the echo message being displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it. I simplified the code for better understanding.

#### Option 1: One file (contact.php), one form, no ajax, no onclick event:

```
<?php
$emailSent = FALSE;

/*
 * ===================================
 * Run operations upon form submission
 * ===================================
 */
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    /*
     * ==========================
     * Validate the posted values
     * ==========================
     */
    if (!isset($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['name'])) {
        $errors[] = 'Please provide a name.';
    }

    if (!isset($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['email'])) {
        $errors[] = 'Please provide an email.';
    } elseif (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errors[] = 'Invalid email.';
    }

    /*
     * ======================================
     * Send the email if all values are valid
     * ======================================
     */
    if (!isset($errors)) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];

        // Send the email here, using the posted values...

        $emailSent = TRUE;
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title>Demo</title>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="messages">
            <?php
            if (isset($errors)) {
                foreach ($errors as $error) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="error">
                        <?php echo $error; ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            } elseif ($emailSent) {
                ?>
                <div class="success">
                    The email was successfully sent.
                </div>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </div>

        <form action="" method="POST">
            <input type="text" id="mail-name" name="name" />
            <input type="email" id="mail-email" name="email" />

            <button class="mail-submit" id="mail-submit" type="submit" name="submit">
                Send e-mail
            </button>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

#### Option 2: Two files, an ajax, an onclick event, no form at all:

**contact.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title>Demo</title>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#submit').click(function (event) {
                    $.ajax({
                        method: 'post',
                        dataType: 'html',
                        url: 'send-email.php',
                        data: {
                            'name': $('#name').val(),
                            'email': $('#email').val()
                        },
                        success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                            $('.messages').html(response);
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            var message = 'An error occurred during your request. Please try again, or contact us.';
                            $('.messages').html('<div class="error">' + message + '</error>');
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="messages"></div>

        <div class="contact-form">
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" />

            <button type="button" id="submit" name="submit">
                Send e-mail
            </button>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**send-email.php:**

```
<?php

$response = '';
$emailSent = FALSE;

/*
 * ==========================
 * Validate the posted values
 * ==========================
 */
if (!isset($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['name'])) {
    $errors[] = 'Please provide a name.';
}

if (!isset($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $errors[] = 'Please provide an email.';
} elseif (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $errors[] = 'Invalid email.';
}

/*
 * ======================================
 * Send the email if all values are valid
 * ======================================
 */
if (!isset($errors)) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    // Send the email here, using the posted values...

    $emailSent = TRUE;
}

/*
 * ==============================================================
 * Assign the corresponding message (with error or success class)
 * ==============================================================
 */
if (isset($errors)) {
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        $response .= '<div class="error">' . $error . '</div>';
    }
} elseif ($emailSent) {
    $response .= '<div class="success">The email was successfully sent.</div>';
}

/*
 * ==================
 * Print the response
 * ==================
 */
echo $response;
```

#### Optional: Option 1 with client-side validation as well:

You can validate the form before submission and, if at least one field is not valid (empty value, false email address, etc), you can stop the submission and display a corresponding error message instead:

```
<?php
$emailSent = FALSE;

/*
 * ===================================
 * Run operations upon form submission
 * ===================================
 */
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    /*
     * ==========================
     * Validate the posted values
     * ==========================
     */
    if (!isset($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['name'])) {
        $errors[] = 'Please provide a name.';
    }

    if (!isset($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['email'])) {
        $errors[] = 'Please provide an email.';
    } elseif (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errors[] = 'Invalid email.';
    }

    /*
     * ======================================
     * Send the email if all values are valid
     * ======================================
     */
    if (!isset($errors)) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];

        // Send the email here, using the posted values...

        $emailSent = TRUE;
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title>Demo</title>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                // The form will not submit before all fields are valid.
                $('.contact-form').submit(function (event) {
                    var messages = [];

                    var name = $.trim($('#name').val());
                    var email = $.trim($('#email').val());

                    // Validate user input.
                    if (name === '') {
                        messages.push('Please provide a name.');
                    }

                    if (email === '') {
                        messages.push('Please provide an email.');
                    }

                    // Display the error messages, if any.
                    if (messages.length > 0) {
                        $('.messages').html('');
                        for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                            $('.messages').append('<div class="error">' + messages[i] + '</div>');
                        }

                        // Abort the form submission.
                        return false;
                    }

                    // Continue the form submission.
                    return true;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="messages">
            <?php
            if (isset($errors)) {
                foreach ($errors as $error) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="error">
                        <?php echo $error; ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            } elseif ($emailSent) {
                ?>
                <div class="success">
                    The email was successfully sent.
                </div>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </div>

        <form class="contact-form" action="" method="POST">
            <input type="text" id="mail-name" name="name" />
            <input type="email" id="mail-email" name="email" />

            <button class="mail-submit" id="mail-submit" type="submit" name="submit">
                Send e-mail
            </button>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Of course, for option 2, you can achieve such a validation easily, by including the validation code inside the onclick handler, and not running the ajax request if the input is not valid.

Good luck!

Comment: I've tried option 1 while you were writing option 2. And it worked perfectly. I just have to ask one more question, which one do you recommend to use? Option 1 or 2?

But for the rest, I appreciate that you took the time to help me with my question, thanks alot.

Comment: @Joe I'm glad it worked, the option 1. Actually, regarding this kind of task, the user is used with both options. Have a form, complete it, submit it, receive message after refresh (or no refresh), done. Though, on one hand, if the user has some "problems" with her/his javascript (e.g. js is deactivated or so), the option 1 is the proper one, because does not rely on js code at all. E.g. the form will submit and the email will be sent.

Comment: @Joe On the other hand, who has "problems" with javascript these days? :-)) The days when the user didn't have js activated are looong gone. All websites rely on js and jquery today. And, because the second option uses ajax, the page (contact.php) will not refresh at all. Just the message will be filled (after email was sent). Hence, I would personally recommend the option 2.

Comment: @Joe I didn't read all your message... Thanks for the appreciation. You are welcome.

Comment: @Joe, I updated my answer with an optional code. Maybe it will be of help for you in the future. Bye.

Answer (score 1):

That just CAN'T be in one single file. You need two.

Try like this... And edit your question with some new issue if any.

And notice the **submit** event handler... Instead of a click handler.

**page.html:**

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <ul class="form-style-1">
      <li>
          <input type="text" id="mail-name" name="name" class="field-divided" maxlength="15"  placeholder="Voornaam *" />&nbsp;<input type="text" id="mail-lastname" name="lastname" class="field-divided" maxlength="15" placeholder="Achternaam" >
      </li>
      <li>
          <input type="email" id="mail-email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail *" class="field-long" maxlength="40" >
      </li>
      <li>
          <input type ="text" id="mail-phone" name="phone" placeholder="Telefoonnummer" class="field-long" maxlength = "15">
      </li>
      <li>
          <select name="subject" id="mail-subject" class="field-select" >
          <option disabled value="" selected hidden >--Onderwerp-- *</option>
          <option value="Kennismakingsgesprek">Kennismakingsgesprek</option>
          <option value="Meer informatie">Meer informatie</option>
          <option value="activiteit">Aanmelding activiteit</option>
          <option value="Vraag/klacht">Vraag/klacht</option>
          <option value="Contact">Overig</option>
          </select>
      </li>
      <li>
          <textarea name="information" id="mail-information"  placeholder =" Je bericht *"class="field-long field-textarea" maxlength="2000"></textarea>
      </li>
      <button class="mail-submit" id="mail-submit" type="submit" name="submit">Send e-mail</button>
      <span class="form-message"></span>
  </ul>
</form>

<script>

$("form").on("submit",function(event){  // Submit handler!
  event.preventDefault();
  var name = $("#mail-name").val();
  var lastname = $("#mail-lastname").val();
  var email = $("#mail-email").val();
  var phone = $("#mail-phone").val();
  var subject = $("#mail-subject").val();
  var information = $("#mail-information").val();
  $.post("contact.php",
      {
        name: name,
        lastname: lastname,
        email: email,
        phone: phone,
        subject: subject,
        information: information,
        submit: "yes"
      },
      function(data){
          $(".form-message").html( data );
      }
  );
});
</script>
```

**contact.php:**

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {


  $email_to = "#";

  $email_subject = "#";

  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $phone = $_POST['phone'];
  $subject = $_POST['subject'];
  $information = $_POST['information'];


  $errorEmpty = false;
  $errorEmail = false;

  if (empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($subject) || empty($information)) {
    echo "<span class='form-error'>Voer alle velden in!</span>";
    $errorEmpty = true;
  }
  elseif (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "<span class='form-error'>Geef een geldig E-mail!</span>";
    $errorEmail = true;
  }
  else {
    $formcontent=" Naam: $name \n\n Achternaam: $lastname \n\n Email: $email \n\n Telefoon: $phone \n\n Onderwerp: $subject \n\n Informatie: $information";
    $mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
    $headers = "From: ". htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']) ." <" . $_POST['email'] . ">\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    mail($email_to, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader);
    echo "<span class='form-success'>E-mail has been sent!</span>";
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two javascript events happening here. You have the form submission event which is triggered by the button of type="submit". That same button its triggering an `onclick` event. Instead, you could add an Id to the form and listed to a `onSubmit` event such as

```
<form id="email-form">
...
</form>

$("#the-form").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  ...
});
```

Then you should be able to make the `ajax` request.